# Power profile of permutation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, exponentiation, symmetric-groups

$P$ denote a matrix from set of all $\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ permutation matrices. We know there is a $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $P^k=I$ the identity.

1. Given an integer $t\in\mathbb N$ how many $n\times n$ permutations have $P^t=I$?
2. What is the minimum $t'$ such that all $n\times n$ permutations have $P^{t'}=I$?
3. What is the smallest $t''>0$ such that every permutation $P$ satisfies $P^{t'''}=I$ at some $1\leq t'''\leq t''$?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the matrix representation plays no role at all, and you might as well (and should have) asked your questions about permutations without mentioning matrices at all ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Yes but I am looking for application purpose and so I do not need abstract interpretations.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. All I want to say is that I advise you to edit your post and remove any mention of matrices in it, because 1) it will make the question clearer for most people here 2) it will make your question shorter, simpler and more attractive and therefore 3) more likely to get answered.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy I want to make it explicit in terms of matrices. That is the whole point of problem.

Comment: I'm afraid you're not getting the point. How is a matrix "more explicit" than a permutation ? Your question is a permutation question, not a matrix question, even if you prefer matrices. Why don't you describe your "application purpose"  ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy It is for computer science and not math.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you prefer matrices over permutations. A large part of computer science uses permutations. It takes less memory to represent a permutation of [1..n] that a matrix of $n^2$ numbers. So, why do you insist on using more memory ?

Comment: They have simpler and a high school student can understand without much background.